QT apps have no text in Ubuntu Mate
I'm running a Mate session on Ubuntu 24.04.4, and noticed that text is missing from all QT applications. The widgets, geometry, theme, is there, but no text.

It's not just text missing from menus, this is a different bug.

It might be similar to this issue, but even if I install kvantum settings, I can't use it, because kvantum settings also renders no text.

It feels a bit like this issue, but that was on Raspian and ultimately attributed to QT build options. We know distro packages are built correctly.
I'm running a Mate session on Ubuntu 22.04.4, and noticed that none of the QT apps can draw their UI components. The geometry is there but text is missing entirely.

Installing qt6-base-dev and the various packages it pulls in changed nothing.

Installing qt6-wayland and the various packages it pulls in changed nothing.

All available qt*-gtk* packages are installed.


I assume it's a font problem? Not sure; Slightly surprised the package manager doesn't sort it out. Apt-reinstalling the affected applications does nothing.
How can I fix this?
Edit:
I found only one forum post describing a similar issue.
The solution involves qtconfig, which does not exist for QT5.
This Reddit thread says to use qt5ct, but I cannot because this is a QT GUI application and therefore its interface does not render. It seems the next step is to find a command-line way to set the plastique GUI style for QT5?
